# Using str_extract_all and unnest but losing rows from NA

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I'm using `str_extract()` and `str_extract_all()` to do some look around regex. There are zero, one, or multiple results, so I want to `unnest()` the multiple results into multiple rows. The unnest does not give all rows in the output, because of the character(0) in ab_all (I'm assuming).

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_tbl <- tibble(clmn = c("abcd", "abef, abgh", "xkcd"))

ab_tbl <- my_tbl %>% 
  mutate(ab = str_extract(clmn, "(?<=ab)[:alpha:]*\\b"), 
         ab_all = str_extract_all(clmn, "(?<=ab)[:alpha:]*\\b"), 
         cd = str_extract(clmn, "[:alpha:]*(?=cd)"))

ab_tbl %>% unnest(ab_all, .drop = FALSE)
```

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  clmn       ab    cd    ab_all
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 abcd       cd    ab    cd    
2 abef, abgh ef    NA    ef    
3 abef, abgh ef    NA    gh
```

*Edit:* Expected output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  clmn       ab    cd    ab_all
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 abcd       cd    ab    cd    
2 abef, abgh ef    NA    ef    
3 abef, abgh ef    NA    gh 
4 xkcd       NA    xk    NA
```

The row with xkccd is not given in the output. Is it something to do with the str_extract_all or the unnest or should I change my approach?

Comment: Hi nmoorenz, could you add a data frame to your question that makes explicit the output you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be we can change the length that are 0 to `NA` and then do the `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
ab_tbl %>%
    mutate(ab_all = map(ab_all,  ~ if(length(.x) ==0) NA_character_ else .x)) %>% 
     unnest
```

NOTE: Assuming that the patterns in `str_extract` are correct